# How to manage clients orders in MODx?

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution, formit

I have form (formit) in my MODX website.

After filling in all fields *(name, email, telephone number, address etc)* by client I receive an email with information. Then I create new document named with his *email* where I put all the information *(name, email, telephone number, address etc)*, in this document client fills other fields (including date, time etc) choosing options speacially created for him and products and then I again receive email. I'm copying information from these two emails in excel file.

How can I make this process automated? Can I have clients database in MOdx and work with it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your custom hook - https://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/formit/formit.tutorials-and-examples/formit.examples.custom-hook
In this hook you may do what you want - create resource with specific fields, send redirect to new page. For second form you may write hook, which register user with specific fields and after all you may create snippet for export to excel all this registered users.

( For redirect to newly created resource you need to clear cache before redirect `$modx->cacheManager->clearCache();` )